# Blender 4.02 where is Alpha over in the compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

Where is the Alpha over node in the Compositor for Blender 4.02?

Comment: Add menu or shift + A >Color >mix > alpha over

Comment: If you had waited for an answer on your previous question, this one would have been obsolete. Be patient. Not everyone is sitting here waiting to answer every question the moment it was posted.

Comment: @Emir .. if you just pop this in as an answer, it can be accepted and closed out.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the <kbd>ADD menu</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> >go to Color > Mix.

[image]